# Are nested for loops always O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm struggling coming up with a complexity for this code (this isn't a homework problem, I'm just trying to understand this concept):

```
public static boolean boxesHaveItem(List<Box> boxes, Item object) {
    for (Box box : boxes) {
        for (Item item : box.getItems()) {
            if (item.equals(object)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because there are nested for loops, your instict would be O(n^2), but that doesn't make sense because the number of items in a box is unrelated to the number of boxes I'm passing to this method.

Maybe O(mn), where m = average # of items in a box, n = # of boxes?

I was thinking O(n) would be best, where n is the total # of items in all of the boxes passed to the function, but that's kinda weird because they aren't directly passed to the function.

Comment: Indeed *O(n)* where *n* is the total number of items. Nothing weird about it though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have multiple choices here. When talking about complexities you should choose a dependency which is **useful** for your audience.

The method clearly depends on the amount of **items**, it yields `Theta(|items|)`. So if `n` is the amount of items, then you have `Theta(n)`, that is absolutely correct.

---

If there is a **dependency from items to boxes**, e.g. a box can maximally contain 5 items, then you can also express the complexity depended on the amount of boxes. It then obviously also yields `Theta(|boxes|)`.

If there is **no dependency** then you **can not express** the complexity with the amount of boxes since it then **does not depend on it**.

Just choose whatever you find most appropriate for your audience.

---

### "Are nested for-loops always O(n^2)?"

To your other question, the answer is no. They aren't always `O(n^2)`. You can easily create a situation where one of the loops affects the iterations of the other, yielding a different complexity.

A small constructed example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < i + 5 && j < amount; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The loop may, at first glance, look like `O(n^2)` but the inner loop maximally creates **5 iterations** for every iteration of the outer loop. So we receive only `5 * n` iterations in total, not something like `n^2`. The complexity thus is `O(n)`.